# Domain of $f(x)=e^{\ln \left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}-e^{-\ln \left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}$

Tags: analysis, functions

As a real function, the domain of
$$f(x)=e^{\ln \left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}-e^{-\ln \left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}$$
is empty, as well as its range.
When trying to simplify the expression using complex numbers, it yields **purely real** result: $f(x)=2x$. Shouldn't the domain and range of $f(x)$ be changed accordingly (if we assume principal branch of $\ln$)?

Comment: The domain is empty also the range

Comment: That was mentioned in the post.

Comment: The domain is what it is, why do you think it _should_ be changed? You could also "simplify" $e^{\ln x}$ to $x$, but that doesn't change the fact that $e^{\ln x}$ is only defined for $x > 0$, so its domain isn't as big as the domain of the simplified $x$ _could be_.

Comment: This is really the same as the question of whether $f(x)=\frac{2x^2}{x}$ should have $0$ in its domain, because $f(x)=2x$ in all cases where $x\neq 0.$

Comment: By the way, the function is $2x$ on the reals using **any** branch of $\ln$ that contains the negative reals in the domain.  We have $e^{\ln y}=y$ for any branch of $\ln.$ What fails is $\ln(e^y)=y$ ifor some $y,$ given any branch of $\ln.$

Comment: $e^{\ln x}=x$ for all complex values of $x$ no matter which branch of $\ln$ you choose, so there is no need to assume the principal branch. (Likewise it doesn't matter which square root you use, as long as you use the same square root function in both places.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, a function really isn't defined until you define the domain.

It is a common exercise to ask, say:

> What is the domain of: $$f(x)=\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2\tag{1}$$

Now, $f(x)=x$ where $f$ is defined. And if we take $\sqrt{\cdot}$ to mean a complex branch of the square root function, then $f(x)$ could have a domain equal to any subset of $\mathbb C,$ the complex numbers, and $f(x)=x.$

But the implicit assumption in such problems is that we are talking about the real versions of functions like $\sqrt{\cdot},$ and we are looking for the largest set of real $x$ where the composition of the functions used are defined.

For example, in my case, $f(x)=g(h(x))$ where $g(x)=x^2$ and $h(x)=\sqrt{x},$ where $g$ and $h$ have domain and ranges equal to subsets of the reals. In particular, $x$ can be in the range of $g(h(x))$ if $x$ is in the domain of $h$ and $h(x)$ is in the domain of $g.$

So the answer to the domain of (1) is $x\geq 0,$ or rather the set $\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x\geq 0\}.$

However, this all depends on context.

In reality, a function isn't defined until you tell us the domain[*], and the meaning of the terms in your expression. The question is really:

> Given the real functions $\ln x,e^x,\sqrt{x},$ what is the largest domain in the reals such that the function: $$f(x)=e^{\ln\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}-e^{-\ln\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}$$ makes sense as a real-valued function.

---

[*] In more precise/advanced language, you also need the "co-domain," but that's really irrelevant here, and probably not something you need to understand yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing a composition of functions:

$dom_{f\circ g} = \{x\in dom_g ~\colon~ g(x)\in~dom_f \} $`

and by operating the inside of the function, you use properties without considering the original domain.

So and the end, it yields $2x$ but in the original domain.